# User authentication with Perfect Swift

Tags: swift, authentication, stormpath, perfect

Is there a good method for implementing user authentication with Perfect Swift? Something of a kind with this:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/85528/user-accounts-ios-ruby-rails-swift

I really like the idea of only developing in Swift for server and client, but I've never tried implementing user-authentication in an app, so I'm not sure if this is the sort of thing that would be done through Perfect, or whether I should be looking at doing this with another service.
So far I've built out the following tutorial with Perfect and it works well enough to get a good feel for the process: http://www.chrismanahan.com/creating-a-web-service-swift-perfect

**EDIT 1:**

I found a good method for authentication called stormpath, however, while they're site talks briefly in a blog post about server side swift (https://stormpath.com/blog/swift-on-the-server-today) as far as I can tell the backend api for this has to be javascript. Is there a way to use stormpath in a perfect database?

Comment: Hey Ethan, check out Turnstile -- I've released 1.0 for the Perfect integration, and can be used today. https://github.com/stormpath/Turnstile-Perfect. Unfortunately, Stormpath itself doesn't have a Perfect integration, but we may decide to add it in the future if enough people start using Turnstile!

Comment: Hi Edward, just got a chance to try out Turnstile. However, it seems to fail at build time with an error that the "TurnstilePerfect" object is an "unresolved identifier" despite having successfully imported Turnstile. Any ideas?

Comment: Figured it out. You need to update your documentation to specify "import TurnstilePerfect" not "import Turnstile"

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the docs. Let me know how it works for you!